# How to get url of repository with Redmine and Subversion?

Tags: svn, repository

I have a beginner question with an SVN repository under Bitnami's Subversion and a Redmine stack.

I have the following in a Linux server:
opt/Subversion-1.7.5.0
opt/Redmine-2.2.2.0
opt/MYREPO

I used `svadmin create MYREPO` .

I can add the repository to a Redmine project in the browser administration. It accepts `file:///opt/MYREPO` .

I would like to work with this repository from another computer, through the Internet. (checkout, commit, etc.)
How can I achieve this? What is the address of the said repository? (For example, what URL should I type in if I try to access the repository over the web?)

Thanks for the help,
Sziro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL will depend upon how your server is exposed to the internet, and how you are serving the repository (svnserve, svnserve via ssh, HTTP, HTTPS).

If you have not set up a server yet (it sounds like you haven't), start [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.html). You may find it more convenient to set up a pre-built server package such as [uberSVN](http://www.ubersvn.com/) or [Subversion Edge](http://www.collab.net/products/subversion)

Comment: I use Bitnami's Subversion Stack: http://bitnami.org/stack/subversion
I installed it with the defaults. I believe this program can function as a server. I would like to configure this.

Comment: Then you should read their [documentation](http://wiki.bitnami.org/Components/Subversion). If your repository is behind a firewall, you'll need to forward the ports & find out your external IP or hostname. And you really ought to use svn+ssh or HTTPS for accessing it. Speak with your server administrator.

Comment: UberSVN is no longer available and supported.

Answer (score 1):

It can be found under

```
svn://HOST/pathtorepository
```